# Keycloak devservice fails to have aliased files be injected

Tags: configuration, keycloak, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I'm building a quarkus app and trying to set the ssl certificates for the Keycloak devservice. I am trying to do this through the `resource-aliases` and `resource-mappings` config:

```yaml
"%dev":
  quarkus:
    keycloak:
      devservices:
        start-command: "start-dev --http-enabled=true --hostname-strict=false --hostname-strict-https=false --https-certificate-file=/opt/keycloak/devTest-cert-cert.pem --https-certificate-key-file=/opt/keycloak/devTest-cert-key.pem"
        resource-aliases:
          systemCert: devTest-cert-cert.pem
          systemCertKey: devTest-cert-key.pem
        resource-mappings:
          systemCert: /tmp/keycloakDev/devTest-cert-cert.pem
          systemCertKey: /tmp/keycloakDev/devTest-cert-key.pem
```

However, Keycloak fails to start, complaining that the specified key was not provided. Upon investigating via `docker exec`, I found that the mapped files aren't making it into the running container.

I've tried a bunch of different syntaxes and file locations but nothing seems to take. Unfortunately debugging this seems fairly difficult

Comment: The start command says `/opt/keycloak/` while you copy the resources to `/tmp/keycloakDev`. FYI, the Quarkus test which depends on this feature copies the resources to `/opt/keycloak`

Comment: Sure, I forgot to update the keycloak command for the example. The core issue still is that the files don't make it into the container anywhere, either in `/tmp` or `/opt/keycloak`

Comment: I'm fairly sure I found a bug at this point. Moving this to an issue on git

Answer (score 0):

I ended up version bumping to latest quarkus and issues magically dissapeared.